# React app doesnt communicate with shopify api

Tags: reactjs, shopify

I am trying to connect a react front end with a Shopify API. However, the code that I have written well when I'm using a webhook to test it out. When I replace the webhook URL with Shopify API URL it does not work. according to the network tab in my browser's console Shopify URL doesn't send out any data but it works when the URL is replaced with something else. The API post works with postamn as it is. How can I fix that? My code is as follows

```
var test = ()=> {
    
      let result = fetch(uri,{ 
      method: 'post',
      mode: 'no-cors',
      headers:{
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        "customer": {
          "first_name": "name",
          "last_name": "name",
          "email": "sample@gmail.com",
          "phone": "+15142556011",
          "verified_email": true,
          "password": "sample",
          
        }
      })}).then((response)=>{

      }).catch((error)=>{});
```

Comment: Did you try it with postman to test if shopify can return a response?

Comment: Any errors in Console ? Have you checked the Network tab ?

Comment: No errors show up in the console. The network tab is not showing anything when using the shopify URL. The shopify URL works when suing postman

Comment: Are you making direct request to Shopify APi from the frontend using the `/admin/api/2021-01/..` routes? If yes this should not work and should not be done! If you are making requests to your back-end that makes the request to the API instead the provided code does not show it. Please provide more information, since direct request to the Shopify Admin API from the frontend (especially POST request) should never be done!

Comment: Yes i was trying to do it that way. How can i do it properly?

Comment: You need to make a request to your our back-end server and make the request from there with the proper App keys.